# What does "'tests' module incorrectly imported" mean?

Tags: python, django

I have copied a working test line by line and just changed a few names (at least so I thought) and now I get this very cryptic error: (I have replaced some stuff with FOO, BAR)

```
ImportError: 'tests' module incorrectly imported from 'FOO/exports/tests'. Expected 'FOO/exports'. Is this module globally installed?
```

The problem is that I do not understand the error at all. What does this error message mean?

Complete stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BAR/modeling/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/jonathan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/jonathan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/jonathan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/Users/jonathan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/jonathan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/jonathan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/jonathan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/Users/jonathan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 531, in run_tests
    suite = self.build_suite(test_labels, extra_tests)
  File "/Users/jonathan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 451, in build_suite
    tests = self.test_loader.discover(start_dir=label, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jonathan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 206, in discover
    tests = list(self._find_tests(start_dir, pattern))
  File "/Users/jonathan/anaconda/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 267, in _find_tests
    raise ImportError(msg % (mod_name, module_dir, expected_dir))
ImportError: 'tests' module incorrectly imported from 'FOO/exports/tests'. Expected 'FOO/exports'. Is this module globally installed?
```

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: Please add the involved file tree, to check the structure and the file where you are trying to import `tests`

Answer (score 331, accepted):

In my experience, weird ImportErrors when running tests are caused by an ImportError in the tests module itself.

Ensure that your tests module can be imported:

```
$ python manage.py shell
...
>>> import foo.exports.tests
```

**Edit:**

If that causes an error, make sure you do not have both a directory `foo/exports/tests` and a file `foo/exports/tests.py`

Comment: Yes it says that there is no such module. But the file is there. What else can I do?

Comment: Are both `foo` and `exports` proper Python modules, i.e. do they contain an `__init__.py`?

Comment: yes I have `__init__.py` files and my editor (Eclipse) shows the module icon and not the folder icon

Comment: Do you maybe have both a directory `foo/exports/tests` and a file `foo/exports/tests.py`?

Comment: Oh, there was a Django automagic `tests.py` file there. Nice catch. And what a cryptic error message... :(

Comment: the django automatic tests.py caught me as well

Comment: Tank you my friends!!
forgot to turn off the tests.py

Comment: Your edit is what saved me! When running startapp django created a tests.py file. I was able to import tests.py in the shell

Comment: After removing the tests.py file from the app directory, the issue was resolved. The error message was not helpful, as I had both a tests folder and a tests.py file.

Answer (score 119):

As Daniel Hepper said in a comment above, try checking whether you have both a `app/tests` folder and a `app/tests.py` file in your app.

Django `startapp` creates a `tests.py` file automatically so there might be a file that you haven't noticed.

If you simply delete the automatically generated `tests.py` file, it should work. (Obviously you should check the contents of the file before deleting anything!)

Answer (score 31):

In case you have created a directory named `tests` and have written test files inside it, for example `test_views.py`, `test_models.py`, etc., make sure you remove the file `test.py` created automatically by the command `python manage.py startapp`.

Answer (score 8):

In one word: delete test.py or tests folder
I had the same issue when I copied some tests I wrote before in one of my projects into my new projects where I had more than 5 same APIs there.
Usually I do create a new folder called tests and write all my tests in a folder for each app so everything looks better
The mistake I made which led me through this problem was not deleting the test.py file from app folder when I created tests folder in the same app
Because you cant have both tests folder and test.py in the same app.

Comment: That was way more than one word.

Comment: How does this add anything vs what the top answers say?

Answer (score 5):

Try checking whether you have both a  `app/tests` folder and a  app/tests.py

file in your app.

By default a file is automatically called `tests.py` delete this file it the error will be resolved

Comment: How does this add anything to the top answers?

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the list of possible cases.

This can also happen inside a virtual env when the package you're on was locally installed.

In that case you just need to uninstall the version that was installed an "re-link" it (I don't known the correct term) by using the develop command

```
~/dev/stufflib% pip uninstall stufflib
~/dev/stufflib% python setup.py develop
~/dev/stufflib% python setup.py test
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case problem was because I tried to start django test task from symlink to folder with project, not from "real" path. When I run django test task from project folder not using symlink I don't get this error.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you don't have 2 files named test.py in your tree files that way Python should pick the one you wanted to.

Comment: This has already been suggested in a different answer, consider up voting that answer instead of posting another.